# In a mixed model, should all random effects be also fixed?

Tags: mixed-model

In my [textbook](https://books.google.fr/books?id=twEtDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA377&lpg=PA377&dq=commenges%20stats&source=bl&ots=Wb9aqErp0_&sig=ACfU3U373lFFcNnKgUHPT6PyBwaqK8fi3g&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihnfTskKDiAhX0BGMBHfnMDu0Q6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=commenges%20stats&f=false) (in french), the formula of mixed model is written as:

$y = X \beta + Z u + \epsilon$

Here, the author says that $Z$ should be a sub-vector of $X$, without explaining further why.

His example is a mixed model for repeated measures, where fixed effect are `intercept + X + Y + time + X:time` and random effects are `individual_ID + time`. As he presents the example, he considers `individual_ID` as an intercept.

However, I could not find this information anywhere else. Indeed, in numerous courses and tutorials ([this one](https://ase.tufts.edu/gsc/gradresources/guidetomixedmodelsinr/mixed%20model%20guide.html) for instance), there can be random effects (group) which are not included in fixed effects.

Is this rule commonly accepted?

If it is, what is the problem of indluding a random effect without its fixed effect? Are above-mentioned tutorials wrong?

If it is not, why would the author of my textbook write something like this?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why commonly the columns of $Z$ are a subset of the columns of $X$ is because you typically assume that the random effects $u$ have mean zero. The fixed effects that correspond to the random effects (e.g., in your example the fixed-effects intercept and time) quantify the average $y$ for these variables.

If you would put a variable, say $w$, into $Z$ but not in $X$ you would assume that the average change in $y$ for a unit increase in $w$ is zero, which is a strong assumption unless you have a-priori reasons that support that.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, but since you cannot put a grouping variable (high in dimension) in $Z$, does this means that this assumption is always made for groups? Also, could you please take a look at my edit? The match between `individual_ID` and intercept is not clear to me.